# select multiple column with different condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count

User table with following fields.

```
id
agent_id
locality
total
building_type
price
```

I am getting different stats result with following queries

```
SELECT agent_id, COUNT(*) AS stat_1 
FROM users 
WHERE "building_type" = 'single' 
AND ("price" BETWEEN 0 AND 200000) 
GROUP BY "agent_id" 
order by agent_id

SELECT agent_id, COUNT(*) AS stat_2 
FROM users 
WHERE "building_type" = 'single' 
AND ("price" BETWEEN 200001 AND 350000) 
GROUP BY "agent_id" 
order by agent_id

SELECT agent_id, COUNT(*) AS stat_3 
FROM users 
WHERE "building_type" = 'single' 
AND ("price" BETWEEN 3500001 AND 500000) 
GROUP BY "agent_id" 
order by agent_id
```

But I want to get result in same query for all stats like

```
SELECT agent_id, 
       COUNT(*) AS stat_1, 
       COUNT(*) AS stat_2, 
       COUNT(*) AS stat_3 
from users 
where <Conditions>
```

How I can get this result in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT agent_id, 
       COUNT(*) filter (where price BETWEEN 0 AND 200000) as stat_1,
       COUNT(*) filter (where price BETWEEN 200001 AND 350000)  AS stat_2, 
       COUNT(*) filter (where price BETWEEN 3500001 AND 500000)  AS stat_3 
from users 
WHERE building_type = 'single' 
GROUP BY agent_id
order by agent_id
```

Answer (score 8):

Postgres 9.4 solves these kind of problems in an elegant way by adding a `filter` clause that allows you to apply a condition on aggregate functions:

```
SELECT   agent_id, 
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "price" BETWEEN 0 AND 200000) AS stat_1,
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "price" BETWEEN 200001 AND 350000) AS stat_2,
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "price" BETWEEN 3500001 AND 500000) AS stat_3
FROM     users 
WHERE    "building_type" = 'single' 
GROUP BY "agent_id" 
ORDER BY "agent_id"
```

With earlier versions that don't allow a `filter` clause, you could implement the same behavior yourself by applying the aggregate function to a `case` expression. Here, we utilize `count`'s property of ignoring `null`s:

```
SELECT   agent_id, 
         COUNT(CASE WHEN "price" BETWEEN 0 AND 200000 THEN 1 END) AS stat_1,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN "price" BETWEEN 200001 AND 350000 THEN 1 END) AS stat_2,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN "price" BETWEEN 3500001 AND 500000 THEN 1 END) AS stat_3
FROM     users 
WHERE    "building_type" = 'single' 
GROUP BY "agent_id" 
ORDER BY "agent_id"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your answer is also right but for my requirement  only filter clause is work.